# Failing to specify return type for returning a rusqlite::MappedRows

Tags: rust, rusqlite

I would like write a Rust function that, provided a `rusqlite::Statement` and a time interval (from, to), returns a `rusqlite::MappedRows` that I can then use as an interator to read rows from a database.

The `get_mapped_rows` function should return the `MappedRows` struct:

```
fn get_mapped_rows<'stmt>(
    stmt: &'stmt Statement,
    from: u64,
    to: u64
)-> MappedRows<'stmt, FnMut(&Row<'_>) -> Result<FromSql, Error>> {
    stmt
        .query(params![from, to])
            .unwrap()
            .mapped(Box::new(|row| {
                Ok(Box::new(row.get(0)?) as Box<dyn FromSql>)
            }))
}
```

And get_rows below calls it:

```
fn get_rows(conn: &mut Connection) {
    let mut stmt =
        conn.prepare("SELECT dbl_time FROM log WHERE time >= ?1 AND time < ?2")
        .unwrap();

    let mapped_rows = get_mapped_rows(stmt, 2, 4);

    while let Some(row_result) = mapped_rows.next() {
        match row_result {
            Ok(dbl_time) => { println!("dbl_time: {}", dbl_time); },
            _ => panic!("What happened?!"),
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
error[E0782]: trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword
  --> src/main.rs:48:23
   |
48 | )-> MappedRows<'stmt, FnMut(&Row<'_>) -> Result<FromSql, Error>> {
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: add `dyn` keyword before this trait
   |
48 | )-> MappedRows<'stmt, dyn FnMut(&Row<'_>) -> Result<FromSql, Error>> {
   |                       +++

error[E0782]: trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword
  --> src/main.rs:48:49
   |
48 | )-> MappedRows<'stmt, FnMut(&Row<'_>) -> Result<FromSql, Error>> {
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^
   |
help: add `dyn` keyword before this trait
   |
48 | )-> MappedRows<'stmt, FnMut(&Row<'_>) -> Result<dyn FromSql, Error>> {
   |                                                 +++
```

I tried adding `dyn` according to the hints and a lot of other things including `Box`ing the `FnMut` and the `FromSql` part of the result. But no luck. I am getting the feeling that this is not the right way to solve my problem.

**Update:**
This is what made it work:

```
fn get_mapped_rows<'stmt>(
    stmt: &'stmt mut Statement,
    from: u64,
    to: u64
)-> MappedRows<'stmt, impl FnMut(&Row<'_>) -> Result<i64, Error>> {
    stmt
        .query(params![from, to])
        .unwrap()
        .mapped(|row| {
            Ok(row.get(0)?)
        })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a type parameter and using it in place of the traits? I.e. `fn foo() -> FromSql` → `fn foo<F: FromSql>() -> F` and similar for the `FnMut` (or switch that to `impl FnMut`)

Comment: Thanks, that really helped out! I realize now that using `impl FnMut` instead of trying to use `dyn` indicates a compile-time known return value. I also tried out `impl FromSql` in the later part of the return type, but understood that I had to specify a specific type, so I used i64. I'll update the example to make it work accordingly!

Comment: Great, if you got something working you should add an answer in the big box at the bottom of this page.

Comment: Noted, will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by updating the `get_mapped_rows` function to the following:

```
fn get_mapped_rows<'stmt>(
    stmt: &'stmt mut Statement,
    from: u64,
    to: u64
)-> MappedRows<'stmt, impl FnMut(&Row<'_>) -> Result<i64, Error>> {
    stmt
        .query(params![from, to])
        .unwrap()
        .mapped(|row| {
            Ok(row.get(0)?)
        })
}
```

What I learnt here is that you use `impl FnMut` to indicate a type known by the compiler (or rather, a signature I guess?). I tried initially to use `impl FromSql` instead of `i64` in the `Result` but the compiler did not like that.